# Little question about gcd and Fermat pseudoprimes.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

From Wikipedia:

> ...a Carmichael number is a composite number $n$ which satisfies the modular arithmetic congruence relation:
>
> $1)$ $b^{n-1}\equiv 1{\pmod {n}}$
>
> for all integers $b$ which are relatively prime to $n$...
>
> Equivalently, a Carmichael number is a composite number $n$ for which
>
> $2)$ $b^{n}\equiv b{\pmod {n}}$
>
> for all integers $b$.

It's clear to me that $2) \Rightarrow 1)$ if $\gcd(b,n)=1$, but I can't rule out the possibility of $\gcd(b,n) \neq 1$ (so that $1)$ is emptily satisfied) and $2)$ not holding.

> Is it true that if $\gcd(b,n) \neq 1$ then $b^{n}\equiv b{\pmod {n}}$?

Also, regarding Fermat's pseudprimes, many sources define them using the congruence $b^{n}\equiv b{\pmod {n}}$. Other (like Wikipedia) uses the congruence $b^{n-1}\equiv 1{\pmod {n}}$, which seems more restrictive. I know theoretically this is a minor difference, my only doubt is about the available statistics about pseudoprime, to which definition they conform?

Comment: $\newcommand{\gcd}{\operatorname{gcd}}$Say $b=6$ and $n=4$. Then $$\gcd(b,n)=\gcd(6,4)=2\ne 1.$$ But $$\begin{align}b^n &= 6^4 \\ &= 36\times 36 \\ &\equiv 0\times 0 \\ &\equiv 0\pmod{4},\end{align}$$ and $$b=6\equiv 2\pmod{4}.$$ Hence $b^n\not\equiv b\pmod{n}$. This shows that it is **not** generally the case that if $\gcd(b,n)\ne 1$, then $b^n\equiv b\pmod{n}$.

Comment: @Minus One-Twelfth Thanks for you good example, but it leaves open the main question. Are the two definition of Carmichael numbers equivalent? n = 4 doesn't satisfy 1) with b = 3. Is it possible for a number n to satisfy 1) and not satisfy 2) because is not coprime to b for a particular choice of b for which 2) doesn't hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\ (1)\ $ holds

Let $\ p\ $ be a prime factor of $\ n\ $

- If $\ p\ $ divides $\ b\ $, then $\ b^n \equiv b\mod p\ $ is obvious
- If $\ p\ $ does not divide $\ b\ $ , we have $\ b^{n-1}\equiv 1\mod p\ $ implying $\ b^n\equiv b\mod p\ $

Since $\ n\ $ must be squarefree ( a Carmichael number is always squarefree ) , the chinese remainder theorem allows to conclude that with all prime factors of $\ n\ $ , $\ n\ $ itself must divide $\ b^n-b\ $ , showing $\ (2)\ $